# Laravel eloquent query to groupBy on a aggregated value

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get an array/collection as below

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------
| age range             | invoice count | total amount  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| overdue > 60 days     | 200           | 20450         |
| overdue 30 to 60 days | 33            | 3600          |
| due today             | 60            | 5000          |
| due next 7 days       | 200           | 2550          |
| due next 8 to 30 days | 50            | 500           |
| due after 30 days     | 150           | 2432          |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

from a table with Invoice details columns(id, user_id, amount, due_date, status, created_at, updated_at) and I am trying following:

```
$invoice_age = InvoiceDetail::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->select('due_date', DB::raw('(to_days(due_date) - to_days(now())) AS age'))
    ->whereIn('status', ['created', 'viewed])
    ->orderBy('age')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

This gives in an array of age, but I am not able to figure out How do I get `group by age`, `count` and `amount total` for invoices as I showed in the above array table.

**UPDATE:**

Following is the SQL query that helps me, but I need to write a **`eloquent or fluent`** query.

```
SELECT
  x.invoice_age_range,
  count(*)               invoice_count,
  sum(invd_invoicetotal) invoice_amount
FROM
  (SELECT
     CASE
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) BETWEEN (to_days(now()) - 7) AND to_days(now()))
       THEN 'overdue_7_days'
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) BETWEEN (to_days(now()) - 15) AND (to_days(now()) - 8))
       THEN 'overdue_8_to_15_days'
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) BETWEEN (to_days(now()) - 30) AND (to_days(now()) - 15))
       THEN 'overdue_15_to_30_days'
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) < (to_days(now()) - 30))
       THEN 'overdue_30_days'
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) BETWEEN to_days(now()) AND (to_days(now()) + 7))
       THEN 'due_in_7_days'
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) BETWEEN (to_days(now()) + 7) AND (to_days(now()) + 15))
       THEN 'due_in_15_days'
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) BETWEEN (to_days(now()) + 15) AND (to_days(now()) + 30))
       THEN 'due_in_30_days'
     WHEN (to_days(due_date) > (to_days(now()) + 30))
       THEN 'due_after_1_month'
     END invoice_age,
     amount
   FROM invoice_details
   WHERE user_id = 2
         AND status IN ('viewed', 'created')
  ) x
GROUP BY x.invoice_age_range;
```

Thanks,

Karmendra

(I am not at all good at thinking in terms of Sets, thus I suck in SQL queries)

Answer (score 0):

For this you may want to  use raw query and put from in eloquent scope

```
DB::table( DB::raw("your case query here") 
->select ()
->gropby()
```